# Why is App Store app icon not being updated with new release?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, app-store

I released my Xamarin Forms iOS app to the Apple App Store earlier this week. The app icon on my phone is correct, and the app icon in TestFlight is correct. The App Store listing, however, shows the old app icon. I have verified that all images in the AppIcon assets file are correct. I don't see a way to edit the app icon in App Store Connect. What do I need to do to update the app icon in the App Store? Thanks